# Adjust Phone Brightness in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, brightness

I wanted to make an app to regulate the phone brightness (android) but cannot find anything.

The only thing that I found is the screen plugin but visual studio code doesn't accept it.

Do you guy maybe have a practical example that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [screen_brightness](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_brightness/example), like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<double>(
          future: ScreenBrightness().current,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            double currentBrightness = 0;
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              currentBrightness = snapshot.data!;
            }

            return StreamBuilder<double>(
              stream: ScreenBrightness().onCurrentBrightnessChanged,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                double changedBrightness = currentBrightness;
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  changedBrightness = snapshot.data!;
                }

                return Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    FutureBuilder<bool>(
                      future: ScreenBrightness().hasChanged,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return Text(
                            'Brightness has changed via plugin: ${snapshot.data}');
                      },
                    ),
                    Text('Current brightness: $changedBrightness'),
                    Slider.adaptive(
                      value: changedBrightness,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setBrightness(value);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> setBrightness(double brightness) async {
    try {
      await ScreenBrightness().setScreenBrightness(brightness);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      throw 'Failed to set brightness';
    }
  }

  Future<double> get currentBrightness async {
    try {
      return await ScreenBrightness().current;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw 'Failed to get current brightness';
    }
  }
}
```

**Remember** that this package won't work on emulator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was what I needed, I'm now trying to find a way to keep that option active while exiting the app and maybe overwrite the current brightness to get it even lower, maybe I'll try seeing in the plugin page!

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin which IDE doesn’t accept. It seems your flutter sdk or some of the packages you are using is not compatible with that plugin’s latest version. Or maybe plugin is too old.
Try this one: https://pub.dev/packages/screen_brightness Instead of adding pubspec.yaml by hand, it is preferred adding dependencies with `flutter pub add [dependency_name]` . Because it automatically adds compatible version with your flutter sdk and dependencies you are already using.

Comment: Thank you, being a beginner I didn't even knwo that and just tried to add it by hand